# RuntimeError: Factor is exactly singular (and overflow encountered in square in FiPy)

Tags: python, fipy

I was trying to solve pde using FiPy in python. It is showing **RuntimeError: Factor is exactly singular**. This is not the case in these equation but in most of the equations I have computed.
[The equations are-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yWOF.png)

∂u/∂t  = σu(1-u/C)  -  (1+αv)uv/(1+h(1+αv)u)  +D∇^2 u and

∂v/∂t  =  (1+αv)uv/(1+h(1+αv)u) - v +D∇^2 v

```
from fipy import *
nx=ny=100
dx=dy=0.25
L=dx*nx
dt=0.01
sigma=10.0
h=0.1
C=0.8 
alp=0.57 #alpha 
mesh =Grid2D(dx=dx,dy=dy,nx=nx,ny=ny)
u=CellVariable(name='u Variable',mesh=mesh)
v=CellVariable(name='v Variable',mesh=mesh)

u.setValue(GaussianNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh,mean=0.18,variance=0.005))
v.setValue(GaussianNoiseVariable(mesh=mesh,mean=0.28,variance=0.005))

D=35
eq_u=(TransientTerm(coeff=1.0, var=u)==sigma*u*(1-v/C) -((1+alp*v)*v*u)/(1+(1+alp*v)*h*u) +ImplicitDiffusionTerm(coeff=D,var=u)) 
eq_v=(TransientTerm(coeff=1.0, var=v)==((1+alp*v)*v*u)/(1+(1+alp*v)*h*u) +v +ImplicitDiffusionTerm(coeff=1.0, var=v))

#creating viewer
if __name__ == "__main__":
    viewer_u=Viewer(vars=u,datamin=0.,datamax=1.0) 
    viewer_u.plot()
    viewer_v=Viewer(vars=v,datamin=0.,datamax=1.0)
    viewer_v.plot()

#solving
steps=50000
for step in range(steps):
    eq_u.solve(var=u,dt=dt)
    eq_v.solve(var=v,dt=dt)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        viewer_u.plot()
        viewer_v.plot()
```

Error are-

```
C:\Users\Harshit Rathore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fipy\solvers\scipy\linearLUSolver.py:41: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  if (numerix.sqrt(numerix.sum(errorVector**2)) / error0)  <= self.tolerance:
C:\Users\Harshit Rathore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fipy\solvers\scipy\linearLUSolver.py:36: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  error0 = numerix.sqrt(numerix.sum((L * x - b)**2))
C:\Users\Harshit Rathore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fipy\solvers\scipy\linearLUSolver.py:41: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  if (numerix.sqrt(numerix.sum(errorVector**2)) / error0)  <= self.tolerance:
C:\Users\Harshit Rathore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fipy\variables\variable.py:1122: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  return self._BinaryOperatorVariable(lambda a, b: a*b, other)
C:\Users\Harshit Rathore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fipy\variables\variable.py:1122: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  return self._BinaryOperatorVariable(lambda a, b: a*b, other)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\VS_Codes\Python\V_1.py", line 32, in <module>
    eq_v.solve(var=v,dt=dt)
  File "C:\Users\Harshit Rathore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fipy\terms\term.py", line 178, in solve
    solver._solve()
  File "C:\Users\Harshit Rathore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fipy\solvers\scipy\scipySolver.py", line 26, in _solve
    self.var[:] = numerix.reshape(self._solve_(self.matrix, self.var.ravel(), numerix.array(self.RHSvector)), self.var.shape)
  File "C:\Users\Harshit Rathore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fipy\solvers\scipy\linearLUSolver.py", line 34, in _solve_
    permc_spec=3)
  File "C:\Users\Harshit Rathore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\dsolve\linsolve.py", line 326, in splu
    ilu=False, options=_options)
RuntimeError: Factor is exactly singular
```

**Is there any better pde solver in python**
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FiPy code does not agree with your equations. You are solving

[image]

If I correct the FiPy code to agree with your math, then the problem runs much longer before the results diverge (which is why you get `Factor is exactly singular` with the `scipy` LU solver (other solvers have other failure modes, but all diverge)). The divergence appears to be when `u` or `v` either gets very small or negative. It's not completely clear to me as the system seems tolerant of some near-zero and negative values. It's not clear to me whether `u` and `v` should remain positive or not, but things often go badly when they don't.

Now, I would recommend making your equations more [implicit](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.terms.html#module-fipy.terms.implicitSourceTerm), [coupling](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/USAGE.html#coupled-and-vector-equations) them together, and [sweeping](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/FAQ.html#iterations-timesteps-and-sweeps-oh-my), as these equations are quite non-linear and it is unlikely that the results are converged.

I'd also recommend working in 1D while you're debugging. It's easier to see what's going on.